# How to make a split screen video with full height?

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve this split screen video effect on a webpage I am working on. [Here is a picture of the result I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZfUy.jpg)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>NextDoor Pub&amp;Grill</title>
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header__menu full-width">

            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav flex full-width">
                <div class="nav__video flex full-width">
                    <div id="left">
                        <div class="nav__video--left" onclick="expandRight()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!--- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first --->
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoLeft/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right">
                        <div class="nav__video--right" onclick="expandLeft()">
                            <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <!--- Inlcude the video files with .webm file first --->
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.webm">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mp4">
                                <source src="assets/videoRight/loop.mov">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .skin{

    }

    .full-width{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .flex{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav{
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .header__menu{
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    }

    .nav__video{
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #left{
        width: 50%;
        height: inherit;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    #right{
        width: 50%;
        height: inherit;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .nav__video--left{

    }

    .nav__video--right{

    }

    video{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    }

}
```

So, as demonstrated by the code above, the divs that the videos are in are sized to occupy the full height below the top menu bar. However, the videos only display in the upper part of their respective divs. How can I make sure the videos occupy the full white space while retaining the same aspect ratio? (part of each video will be cut off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After futzing around with it for a while, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dn4pdnks/) appears to be the correct CSS combination, giving both a cover effect and full height while taking the banner into account.

`height: calc(100vh - 100px);` gives full height minus header height. The rest is mainly carrying `height` and `width` through the whole element tree so that `video` has the correct dimensions to size against.

Keep in mind that IE doesn't support `object-size` and, without it, this effect can only be accomplished with the help of javascript.

```
.full-width{
  width: 100%;
}

.flex{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.nav{
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.header__menu{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

.nav__video{
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;

}

#left, #right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left{
  background-color: green;
}

#right{
  background-color: yellow;

}

.nav__video--left, .nav__video--right{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.nav__video--left{
  background-color: blue;
}

.nav__video--right{
  background-color: red;
}

video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
video {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bxzf2kq/4/) is a working fiddle I hope matches what you were looking for.

```
.nav__video--left{
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav__video--right{
background-color: red;
}

video{
    object-fit: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have then set `object-fit: cover` so the video fills the fill the entire div and `overflow:hidden;` to hide the parts of the video that extend outside of the div.

Comment: IE does support it, at least the latest version and anything earlier is used by 1%. You're going to have a hard time and sacrifice a fair bit of time getting 100% browser coverage as nice as it would be. I'm sure there's a way you could get around the FF issue. If I get time I'll take a look for you.